# textmate- How to toggle between file drawer/browser and editor?

Tags: textmate, osx-mountain-lion

I have tried both `ctrl-tab` and `command-option-tilda`, but they won't work.

This will be a very useful keyboard shortcut for me, as I switch between drawer and editor quite often.

Answer (score 3):

option-command-tab will switch focus between editor and file browser

via http://textmate.1073791.n5.nabble.com/keyboard-shortcut-to-open-files-in-file-browser-td28117.html

Answer (score -1):

If you are using TextMate 2.
From the View menu select Show File Browser
the keyboard shorcuts are:
control, option, command D

Comment: I believe the question is about switching focus between editor and drawer, not showing/hiding the drawer.